# React: How can I remove a specific div element after clicking its associated button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this component which adds a div and its elements to the dom on button click. The adding part works fine as expected but the issue arises when I want to delete.

Right now when I click on the delete button, it does remove the item but it doesn't remove that specific item which the button is associated with. It just removes the div from the top or bottom.

I have been trying to remove that specific div whose button has been clicked to remove. How can I achieve that?

Here's the [CodeSandbox](https://wotm1.csb.app/).

And here's the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {

  const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState( 1 );

  const handleAddDiv = () => {
    setCounter( counter + 1 );
  };

  const handleRemoveDiv = () => {
    setCounter( counter - 1 );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">

      {
        Array.from(Array( counter )).map(( item, idx ) => (
           <div>
             <div>
               <input type="text" />
               <button onClick={handleRemoveDiv}>Remove</button>
             </div>
           </div>
        ))
      }

      <button onClick={handleAddDiv}>Add</button>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: make an array of ids instead of a counter that you increment, so you will be able to delete by filtering your array by this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not prefered react way of doing things, but this will work:

```
import "./styles.css";

import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

  const handleAddDiv = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  const removeNode = (idx) => document.getElementById(`id-${idx}`).remove();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Array.from(Array(counter)).map((item, idx) => (
        <div key={idx} id={`id-${idx}`}>
          <div>
            <input type="text" />
            <button onClick={() => removeNode(idx)}>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={handleAddDiv}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Generaly if you would like to have it made correactly then you would want to map on a real array and have every item in array eighter having an unique id or simply use map index and then based on which item you click write a function to remove from that array our specific element.

Comment: It worked. But as you said this is not a preferred way, can you please tell what would be the preferred way? May be I'll learn something new.

Comment: Yeah i have describe it below the code, but overall you would prefer to have array of objects and then by mapping you would assign to removeAction an id/index and based on that remove that item from current array. 
If this answers please dont forget to vote on the answer and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

#### Map over an array of unique Ids

First of all, you should map over **an array of items** instead of an integer value.

So, on click of add button, you should push a **unique ID** to the array of items where each ID would denote an item being rendered in your app.

Now, when you click on remove button, you would need to remove that ID from the array of items, which would result in **"deletion"** of that div from the app.

In my case, I have considered `timestamp` as a unique ID but should explore other options for generating unique IDs. Working with indices is [anti pattern in React](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/using-index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-in-react-8e5db3aea3a9) especially when you are mapping over an array in JSX as you would encounter issues at one point of time. So, it's a good idea to maintain unique Ids.

**Note:** *Damian's solution* is not ideal as **DOM Manipulation is avoided** in React.

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const Item = ({ id, removeDiv }) => {
  const clickHandler = useCallback(() => {
    removeDiv(id);
  }, [id, removeDiv]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Remove</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const addDiv = useCallback(() => {
    // using timestamp as a unique ID
    setItems([...items, new Date().getTime()]);
  }, [items]);

  const removeDiv = useCallback((itemId) => {
    // filter out the div which matches the ID
    setItems(items.filter((id) => id !== itemId));
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {items.map((id) => (
        <Item key={id} id={id} removeDiv={removeDiv} />
      ))}

      <button onClick={addDiv}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.app {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array state instead of a counter state, because otherwise you don't know which element has to be removed.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

let counter = 1;
export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([0]);

  const handleAddDiv = () => {
    setArray((prev) => [...prev, counter++]);
  };

  const handleRemoveDiv = (idx) => {
    var arrayCopy = [...array];
    arrayCopy.splice(idx, 1);//remove the the item at the specific index
    setArray(arrayCopy);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((item, idx) => (
        <div key={item}>
          <div>
            <input type="text" />
            <button onClick={()=>handleRemoveDiv(idx)}
            >Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleAddDiv}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I am adding a new item, I give it the value `counter++`, because I will use it as a key, and a key should be unique.

Comment: Thanks mate. This is good. It solved some other issues for me.

Comment: Hey counter's job is only for the key right? You can also increment without using counter right?

Comment: @Zak if you find another way to do it then yes.

Comment: Hey how do you suggest I approach input change? Right now if I use an onChange function and use e.target.value, then all the input fields get the same value. How do you think I can use onChange on specific input field?

Comment: @Zak I would create a Component for the input and delete button, and in that component I would have a useState for the input and handle it in there, so all inputs are handelt seperately.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot